# How to limit permissions of certain Informix users

Tags: permissions, user-controls, informix

I have multiple users on my Informix 12.10 server. I want to limit certain users delete permission in Informix so that particular users cannot delete any tables in Informix.

Comment: Do you mean "delete tables" as in "DROP TABLE", or delete (from) tables?  Only users with RESOURCE or DBA privilege can drop tables; only users with DBA privilege can drop tables they don't own.  Limit the people who have either RESOURCE or DBA privilege.  If you don't want people to delete from tables, revoke delete privilege from PUBLIC and from each user otherwise granted DELETE permission.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "delete tables" as in "DROP TABLE", or delete (from) tables?

If you want to limit the ability to drop (non-temporary) tables, then you should know that only users with RESOURCE or DBA privilege can drop tables; only users with DBA privilege can drop tables they don't own. The cure to this problem is to limit the people who have either RESOURCE or DBA privilege.

If you don't want people to delete from specific tables, revoke delete privilege from PUBLIC (because anyone can do what PUBLIC can do) on each of those tables, and also from each user otherwise granted DELETE permission.  That tends to get a bit verbose, but is doable with a shell script to generate the DDL:

```
for table in "$@"
do
    echo "REVOKE DELETE ON $table FROM PUBLIC;"
    for user in user1 user2 user3 user4
    do echo "REVOKE DELETE ON $table FROM $user;"
    done
done
```

Save the output in a `.sql` file and run it with DB-Access.  You can get much fancier with how you generate the list of users.  You could also generate a comma-separated list of user names and run a single REVOKE statement.  You pays your money and takes your pick.  For a given table (`'elements'` in this example), this SELECT statement lists the users from whom DELETE permission must be revoked:

```sql
SELECT a.grantee, t.owner, t.tabname, t.tabid
  FROM "informix".SysTabAuth AS a
  JOIN "informix".SysTables  AS t ON a.tabid = t.tabid
 WHERE a.tabauth[5] = 'd'
   AND t.tabname = 'elements';
```

That generates more information than you need — the `grantee` column is sufficient — but the extra might help you during debugging.  Note that if 'user1' grants delete permission to 'user2', and 'user3' tries to run the REVOKE statement `REVOKE DELETE ON tablename FROM user2` will not change the permissions.  However, a DBA could run `REVOKE DELETE ON tablename FROM user2 AS user1`.  In other words, the `grantor` matters, as well as the `grantee`.

You might want to make use of the [NODEFDAC](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=products-nodefdac-environment-variable) environment variable (it's short for 'no default DAC', where DAC is 'discretionary access control') when creating tables to deny PUBLIC default permissions on created tables.
However, that's of limited help and simply setting it does not apply the new rules retroactively.